# JsonConverter to String Arrays

Tags: c#, json, json.net

From this Json file;

```
"a": "a",
"b": "b",
"c": "c",
"labels": "[Series A, Series B]"
```

I use Newtonsoft.Json for desirialize:

My class c#:

```
 public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(string []))]
    public string [] labels { get; set; }
```

In another class:

```
dummyObject = (DummyObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JasonFile.ToString(), typeof(DummyObject));
```

I want to get in Javascript this Array of string:

```
 labels = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
```

But I have this error when I try to desirialize:

```
Error creating 'System.String[]'.
```

Where is the error in this code..?

Comment: `"[Series A, Series B]"` isn't an array. `["Series A", "Series B"]` would be.

Comment: I used this idea, and I had the same error: Error creating 'System.String[]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The json file is incorrect

1. Because you are dealing with an object it should start with `{` and end with `}`.
2. The array is wrong

Try this for the file

```
{
  "a": "a",
  "b": "b",
  "c": "c",
  "labels": ["Series A", "Series B"]
}
```

More details can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: I was testing with this variants: "{Series A, Series B}"

"{[Series A, Series B]}"

"{[Series A], [Series B]}", but didn't work the error is the same...is correct this: [JsonConverter(typeof(string []))]??

Comment: No need for the `JsonConverter` attribute.